# Generar recibos en pdf usando un foreach en C# pero me imprime 5 recibos con los mismo datos

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Necesito generar un pdf con  recibos de varios clientes los datos los saco de un Datagridview y solo me genera recibos de la primera fila la idea es que cada página tenga un recibo de diferente cliente

```
 try
            {
                DialogResult ResultadoEliminar = MessageBox.Show("Desea Generar PDF De Recibos De Clientes?", "Generar Pdf", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (ResultadoEliminar == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    SaveFileDialog guardar = new SaveFileDialog();
                    guardar.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".pdf" + ".pdf";
                    if (guardar.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(guardar.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);
                            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs);
                            pdfDoc.Open();
                            //platilla recibo            
                            string paginahtml_texto = Properties.Resources.PlantillaRecibo.ToString();
                            string reporte = LblImprimirRecibos.Text;
                            string idrecibo = string.Empty;
                            string codigoSuministro = string.Empty;
                            string fecha = string.Empty;
                            string Concepto = string.Empty;
                            string Sector = string.Empty;
                            string NombreCliente = string.Empty;
                            string direccion = string.Empty;
                            string Periodo = string.Empty;
                            string deuda = string.Empty;
                            string total = string.Empty;
                            //int deuda;
                            for (int f = 0; f <= DgvRecibos.Rows.Count; f++)
                            {
                                foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvrow in DgvRecibos.Rows)
                                {
                                    idrecibo = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["IdRecibo"].Value);
                                    codigoSuministro = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["CodigoSuministro"].Value);
                                    fecha = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["FechaRecibo"].Value);
                                    Concepto = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["Concepto"].Value);
                                    Sector = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["NombreSector"].Value);
                                    NombreCliente = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["NombreCompleto"].Value);
                                    direccion = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["Direccion"].Value);
                                    deuda = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["Deuda"].Value);
                                    total = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["Total"].Value);
                                    Periodo = Convert.ToString(dgvrow.Cells["Periodo"].Value);

                                    //AGREGAR DATOS A LA PLANTILLA
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@RECIBO", idrecibo);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@CODIGOSUMINISTRO", codigoSuministro);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@DIRECCCION", direccion);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@TIPOSERVICIO", Concepto);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@PERIODO", Periodo);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@USUARIO", NombreCliente);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@SECTOR", Sector);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@DEUDA", deuda);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@TOTAL", total);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@REPORTE", reporte);
                                }
                                pdfDoc.NewPage();
                                {
                                    //ADD IMAGE
                                    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Properties.Resources.logo_sap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                                    img.ScaleToFit(80, 60);
                                    img.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
                                    img.SetAbsolutePosition(pdfDoc.Left - -10, pdfDoc.Top - 65);
                                    pdfDoc.Add(img);

                                    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(paginahtml_texto))
                                    {
                                        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            pdfDoc.Close();
                            fs.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = Convert.ToString(ex);
                MessageBox.Show(error, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi como esta imagen las el resto de páginas pdf tienen la misma información

Comment: Me parece que el primer for esta demás y el pdfNewPage debe estar dentro del foreach.

Comment: Si asi es.el problema es que me imprime recibos repetidos de la primera fila o primer cliente.

Comment: Ah, porque tu plantilla ya no sirve para el segundo porque el primero elimino todas las referencias @Recibo, etc. Baja la asignación de la plantilla al for o utiliza otra variable de resultado para mantener los indicadores de reemplazo en la plantilla. Si haces ``p = p.replace("@A", value) ``entonces p perdió toda referencia a ``@A`` y los subsiguientes registros ya no encuentras @A. Por eso siempre mantiene el primero. Los siguientes no cambian nada

Comment: Muchas gracias Me has ayudado mucho

Comment: llevo dias que no le veo la  manera y me resuelto el problema gracias

Comment: Mucho gusto haberte podido ayudar.

Comment: buenas tardes. tengo un problema y es que cuando son muchos registros y necesito generar 500 recibos el programa se cuelga y no responde hasta que acaba de generar los recibos? me podria dar alguna idea de como evitar eso?

Comment: Hazlo en una tarea Asyncrona: Task t = Task.Run( ()= { using (File..... {  .. } pdfDoc.Close(); } );

Comment: Lo que sigo sin entender ¿por qué recorres el datagrid dentro de otro? El primer for lo recorres utilizando un índice f y luego un arrancas un foreach que recorre todo el datagrid, es decir, por cada fila que lees, recorres el datgrid completo. Y lo peor es que no utilizas la f para nada, fácil ha podido se también un foreach.

Comment: Gracias y el for ya lo saque solo queda el foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que la plantilla deja de ser como tal cuando procesa el primer regustro:

```
paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@RECIBO", idrecibo);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@CODIGOSUMINISTRO", codigoSuministro);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@DIRECCCION", direccion);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@TIPOSERVICIO", Concepto);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@PERIODO", Periodo);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@USUARIO", NombreCliente);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@SECTOR", Sector);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@DEUDA", deuda);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@TOTAL", total);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@REPORTE", reporte);
```

Luego del primer registro las constantes de reemplazo ya no existen porque cambiaste la plantilla. Deberías asignar la plantilla a otra variable y utilizar ests:

```
Var paginahtml_texto = plantillahtml;
paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@RECIBO", idrecibo);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@CODIGOSUMINISTRO", codigoSuministro);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@DIRECCCION", direccion);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@TIPOSERVICIO", Concepto);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@PERIODO", Periodo);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@USUARIO", NombreCliente);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@SECTOR", Sector);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@DEUDA", deuda);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@TOTAL", total);
                                    paginahtml_texto = paginahtml_texto.Replace("@REPORTE", reporte);
```

En el ejemplo de arriba he utilizado `plantillahtml` que viene a ser lo que lees de Prperties.Resource.